# How is the Damage Roll Multiplier for Kinetic Knights in Pathfinder: Kingmaker Calculated?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

For example, some of my characters have damage rolls of 1d6+5, and my character (a Kinetic knight using a kinetic blade) has a damage roll of 4d6+7.

I am aware that 4d6+7 means that I roll my dice four times, add the result, and add it to 7, giving me an attack value anywhere between 11 (4+7) to 31 (24+7). I am also aware that some weapons have fixed damage roll multipliers (as shown on the Pathfinder Wiki).

However, I haven't found any sources explaining how exactly the damage multiplier is calculated for
my kinetic knight's kinetic blade. I have seen other people with damage roll multipliers of 10 (10d6+1, for example). The game doesn't really explain, and I have been trawling forums and the in-game encyclopedia in search of the exact formula, but to no avail.

Thanks in advance for answering my question!

Comment: Is this about Pathfinder 1e, the pen-and-paper role-playing game system, or _Pathfinder: Kingmaker_, the video game? The body of your question seems to be about the former (maybe; a damage roll of 10d6+1 is... unlikely, in PF1e), but the title references the latter (but then, _Kingmaker_ was a Pathfinder adventure path first, before it was a video game). Anyway, if your question is about the Pathfinder 1e RPG system, we can help but need that to be clear. If it’s about the video game, we can’t help but [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com) is a sister site for this sort of question.

Comment: @KRyan, it's about Pathfinder: Kingmaker, the video game, but I've heard that the video game uses the same mechanics as the roleplaying system, so any answers for the Pathfinder 1e RPG system would be helpful as well :)

Comment: They don’t. The video game’s systems are inspired by the roleplaying system’s; there are certainly similarities but they differ in many, if not most, of the details. Several things in your question don’t actually make sense in the roleplaying system; those could have been chalked up to new player misunderstanding, but for all I know they’re perfectly correct for the video game. If you want to ask about what’s different between the two, we might be able to handle that, but that’s a different question from this one.

Comment: Ahh, okay @KRyan, fair enough. I'll do that then, so thanks for putting up with my noob question :)

Comment: Please note that Arqade likely could handle _this_ question; it’s worth checking them out to learn more about the game.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: As far as I know, the ability works exactly the same in both. The damage is equal to your kinetic blast, (not adjusted for elemental overflow tho) which is 1d6+1 per 2 levels + con mod.  This means that at level 10, it will do 5d6+5 + con damage. If you use a composite blast to form the infusion, it instead will do 10d10+10+con (if a physical blast is used.) or 5d6/10d6 + 1/2 con if an energy blast is used. The former targets AC, while the latter targets touch AC.